# bash comes in a state that treats a string of three words as a string of one word, why?

Tags: bash

bash ver 5.2.15(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu).

Many bash are running in terminals in windows under Konsole in KDE.

Since a few days one of these shells bash is come into an odd state: a string of three words is treated as a string of one word.

The test code is:

```
WEy="a b c"; read -a WEarr <<< "$WEy"; WE_noe=${#WEarr[@]}; echo "WE_noe: ~$WE_noe~"; for ((i=0; $i<$WE_noe; i++)); do echo "$i:: ${WEarr[$i]}"; done
```

The wrong output is:

```
WE_noe: ~1~
0:: a b c
```

The SPACEs between a b c are retained.

The correct output should be:

```
WE_noe: ~3~
0:: a
0:: b
0:: c
```

The cause may be typos, I dont know.

Please help:

What is the cause,

what a special state of bash is
this,

how can I reset bash to normal state?

Commands "tset" and "reset" do not help.

Regards

== addon 08.02.2023::12:00

outputs of

```
stty -g
```

for this bad bash and for a good bash are different.

They differ in the first value before the first colon.

good bash is

```
5100: ...
```

bad bash is

```
6506: ...
```

I have to work on.

Regards

Comment: It's most likely because the `IFS` in effect consists of no space. You can compare `WEy="a b c"; IFS= read -a WEarr <<< "$WEy"; for i in "${WEarr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done` and `WEy="a b c"; IFS=' ' read -a WEarr <<< "$WEy"; for i in "${WEarr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done`

Comment: == 08.02.2023 12:20  @Tom Yan :: many, many thanks, that it is. With IFS='  '  the output was corrected. So I have looked on IFS. In the bad bash it was only 0x0a, but not 0x20 0x09 0x0a as it shpuld be.  I have corrected IFS and bash is again normal. Problem solved, thanks, thanks, Regard

Comment: == 08.02.2023 12:46 ... but not totally solved. In the bad bash the output of stty -g still diffrs. Is equally so as it was before correction of IFS. I have to work on. -- Has the wrong stty setting corrupted IFS or has false IFS corrupted stty setting -- or is there a third player? Regards